# React Native Android performance

Tags: performance, react-native

Are there any benchmarks of how React Native Android performance compares to traditional native Android apps?
https://code.facebook.com/posts/895897210527114/dive-into-react-native-performance/ implies the performance has improved but it would be nice to know actual numbers, especially on older Android phones.

Comment: It's not an answer of your question but I think that this can be helpful to you: https://launchdrawer.com/i-made-react-native-fast-you-can-too-9e61c951ce0#.cx5y61frv

Comment: [vikasverma92](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3773648) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65018100) saying "There is an excellent post on medium comparing performance between react-native, native, and flutter. https://medium.com/swlh/flutter-vs-native-vs-react-native-examining-performance-31338f081980"